# Reading Dataset statistics generated by StatisticsGen

Tags: tensorflow-data-validation

I looked at the TFX guide (https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide), and I was able to run the pipeline. The StatisticsGen component wrote Dataset statistics to a file on disk. How do I visualize the stats stored in the file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The StatisticsGen component writes the statistics protocol buffer in a TFRecord file. You can visualize the statistics in a Jupyter notebook as follows:

```
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
STATS_OUTPUT_PATH = ''
stats = tfdv.load_statistics(STATS_OUTPUT_PATH)
tfdv.visualize_statistics(stats)
```